# Metaphor with coronavirus

Tags: metaphors

**Can you suggest some good metaphor sentences with reference to or relating to coronavirus??**

> A metaphor is a figure of speech that is used to make a comparison between two things that aren't alike but do have something in common. Unlike a simile, where two things are compared directly using like or as, a metaphor's comparison is more indirect, usually made by stating something is something else. A metaphor is very expressive; it is not meant to be taken literally. You may have to work a little to find the meaning in a metaphor.
>
> [Kids dictionary](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/metaphor-examples-for-kids.html)

Comment: Are you talking about the virus itself (SARS-CoV-2) or the disease (Covid-19)?

Comment: I am talking about covid-19

Comment: When you’re quoting words that are not your own, you need to attribute it. Please remove or add attribution for what you plagiarized in your question.

Comment: I usually say "I never metaphor I didn't like", but in the case of COVID I'll make an exception.

Comment: Because you are new to the site I have edited your question to answer the comment from @Laurel. I do. You probably quoted material without knowing the site conventions for displaying it as a quote, so it is unkind to accuse you of plagiarism. On this site you should remember to show where material comes from, and you should show us what work you have done yourself before asking about the remaining thing you cannot answer yourself.

Comment: Note that in the treatment usually espoused on ELU, the definition stops at 'A metaphor is a figure of speech that is used to make a comparison between two things that aren't essentially alike but do have _something_ in common.' Similes (as X as [a] Y; like a Y ...) thus form a subset. 'John is as bold as a lion' is a metaphor presented in the form of a simile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examples might be: *COVID-19 is a shadow that puts out our lights*; *It is a hail of death*; *It is the Devil’s roulette* ... and so on.